# Oracle Service Bus tracing API

Tags: java, oracle, api, esb, osb

Is there any way to invoke a proxy service from java code and receive it's message tracing (like in OSB test console)?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there is no documented way to do this. OSB API does not provide this functionallity too.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there isn't, but Oracle does sell something that does monitoring through Java Agent API to provide some of the functionality you're thinking of:  [Oracle Business Transaction Management](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/btm-496775.html).

It's part of the **Application Performance Management** suite of tools, but by using [Java Agents](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076676/learn-java/an-introduction-to-agents.html) it tracks all the calls made outbound to the system, letting you monitorig SOA, OSB, JEE, EJB, JDBC, etc., types of probes.

I don't expect this to answer your very specific use-case, but it might be something worthwhile to look at if you find you want to do something like this everywhere.